# Is it possible to assign a hotkey to open a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I push `cntr + t` a new tab is opened it possible to assign `cntr + x` to open an extension  in the same fashion as

```
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "blank.html"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your extension can declare commands, and default keyboard shortcuts to map to them, in the `"commands"` section of its manifest. Refer to [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/commands) for details.